# Запятая перед "словно"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "словно" в этом предложении:

... вгляделся в силуэт, пронесшийся мимо дома(,) словно местное привидение.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос непростой.

**Вариант 1 (с обособлением)**

Вгляделся в силуэт, пронесшийся мимо дома,  словно местное привидение.

С одной стороны, в состав обособленного определительного оборота может входить **обособленный сравнительный оборот**, например:

Цветы глядят с тоской влюблённой, безгрешно чисты, как весна. 
Я долго любовался его лицом, кротким и ясным, как вечернее небо.

**Вариант 2 (без обособления)**

Вгляделся в силуэт, пронесшийся мимо дома словно местное привидение.

С другой стороны, здесь сильное глагольное управление: "пронесся словно привидение", а не "силуэт, словно привидение", пауза будет искажать смысл, поэтому оборот лучше не  обособлять.

Эта тема не раскрывается в обычных справочниках, но тем не менее обсуждается, например: [СРАВНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ОБОРОТ | books.house](http://books.house/russkiy-yazyik/sravnitelnyiy-oborot-23381.html).
(Хотя в этом источнике примеры не самые удачные).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос простой. Читаем у Розенталя:

§115. Сравнительный оборот

1. Запятыми выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты, начинающиеся союзами словно, будто, как будто, точно, чем, нежели, что и др...

Примечание. Не выделяются запятыми сравнительные обороты с указанными союзами, входящие в состав сказуемого или тесно связанные с ним по смыслу.

(Здесь этого и близко нет, а потому запятая ставится).

Comment: Лес стоял как сплошная стена.  Тесная связь со сказуемым, нет запятой, Вы согласны?  А теперь: Мы увидели лес, стоявший как сплошная стена. Будете обособлять?

Comment: Еще раз:

Запятыми выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты, начинающиеся союзами СЛОВНО, БУДТО, КАК БУДТО, ТОЧНО, ЧЕМ, НЕЖЕЛИ, ЧТО и др...

У автора союз "словно", о союзе "как" разговор отдельный. И никакой тесной связи со сказуемым и близко нет.

Comment: Об общих  правилах рассказываете, а на конкретный вопрос почему-то не отвечаете. Ну да ладно. Союзы СЛОВНО и КАК - синонимы.    В заданном предложении "пронесся как привидение"/пронёсшийся как привидение" оборот является необособленным обстоятельством (не будем забывать, что причастие - это всего лишь форма глагола).  Впрочем, если речь идет о школьном уровне,  ПРОЩЕ поставить запятую, чем задумываться над вопросом, почему она "не читается".

Comment: >> *Союзы СЛОВНО и КАК - синонимы*

Однако пунктуация бывает разной. 

>> *ПРОЩЕ поставить запятую, чем задумываться над вопросом, почему она "не читается"*

Вы опять про ваши любимые "паузы"... Зачем выдумывать, когда есть четкое правило?